# can i use gradle to re-skin my app at compile time?

Tags: java

I want to create an app where it only has one code base and I want to specify, perhaps in gradle, where it can access its assets (paths to images and sounds, maybe even colors values, app version and connection strings).

I hope this illustration clarifies what I'm aiming for.

[image]

How could I go about doing something like that? How would I be able to  bind those values? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, there are many ways actually.  What you may want to look at first is something called [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).  You can keep your core classes the same and just swap out resource files based on the flavor specifications. You can add/remove flavors in your build.gradle

Comment: @i am E thank you this is just what I was looking for.